# How do I print in grayscale on Canon Pixma MP280?

Tags: printing, settings, canon

From my Macbook Pro (10.5.1), the print dialog has no grayscale option (screenshot below).

I opened settings, and there is a color option in each Preset. The Presets are read-only.

I guess I am supposed to click *Duplicate* and edit a copy, but the *Duplicate* button is disabled (screenshot at bottom), regardless of which of the three Presets is selected.

How do I print in grayscale or black-and-white?

[image: printer dialog]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set Grayscale printing, click   **Layout**, then **Quality & Media**.  Not the most obvious choices in an OS famed for UX!